# The server is losing connection. Is it a hardware issue or a software issue?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, debian, debian-squeeze, ubuntu-11.10

I have a proxy server (with Squid3) setup in an old machine.

Recently, while downloading, I lose the connection. At that time, I can't even SSH into the proxy. When I press a key in the keyboard (of the proxy server) the connection comes back! I tried with Ubuntu 11.10 and Debian 6 - both have the same issue!

I also checked the "ifconfig" result... It showed 1269 dropped packets :

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0c:76:c2:de:ef
          inet addr:10.0.0.100  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::20c:76ff:fec2:deef/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:964533 errors:0 dropped:1269 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1183810 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:925950757 (883.0 MiB)  TX bytes:926726143 (883.7 MiB)
          Interrupt:23 Base address:0xe400
```

I checked again after another connection drop and the dropped count increased to 1701. When I issue "ip -s link show eth0", it gave me this :

```
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0c:76:c2:de:ef brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    RX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped overrun mcast
    941833855  980298   0       0       0       0
    TX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped carrier collsns
    942639027  1201568  0       0       0       0
```

I like to know whether it's a hardware problem or a software problem... If it's the software, how can I fix this?

PS : I just changed the network card and still the problem is there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure but seems that is not a Hardware problem, at least is not related to the network card as both cards are failing, Which Server (Brand and model) do you have?

Comment: Now I have a Debian 6 server!

Comment: Sorry, I mean, is a generic machine or branded?

Comment: Oh... its an old AMD machine... i think its 1.6GHz... Ram 640MB (Motherboard MSI) Custom built!

Comment: You mention that the problem seems to solve when you press the button server starts to work again, well, probably is something related to the energy saving configuration, try to disable and check if the problem remains.